# Aborting pending http request in Angular not aborting

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

I am trying to abort an $https request in Angular when a new request is triggered. However, the request still appears to be pending in Chrome's dev tool. Am I doing anything wrong here?

allMarkersRequest.abort() gets fired when allMarkersRequest is not null. So deferredAbort.resolve() is called, but the program still ends up going through .then().

```
var allMarkersRequest = null;

function getAllMarkersForSearch() {
    if (allMarkersRequest) {
        allMarkersRequest.abort();
        console.log('Aborting all markers request');
    }

    var deferredAbort = $q.defer();

    var url = Routing.generate('ajax_search_geo_all_markers');

    var req = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url
    });

    allMarkersRequest = req.then(function (data) {
        createMarkers(data.data);

        $rootScope.$broadcast('map:markers:updated', markers);
    }, function (error) {
        // Display error message
    });

    allMarkersRequest.abort = function() {
        deferredAbort.resolve();
    };

    allMarkersRequest.finally(function () {
        allMarkersRequest.abort = angular.noop;
        deferredAbort = req = allMarkersRequest = null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not include the timout parameter in request

var allMarkersRequest = null;

```
function getAllMarkersForSearch() {
    if (allMarkersRequest) {
        allMarkersRequest.abort();
        console.log('Aborting all markers request');
    }

    var deferredAbort = $q.defer();

    var url = Routing.generate('ajax_search_geo_all_markers');

    var req = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        timeout: deferredAbort
    });

    allMarkersRequest = req.then(function (data) {
        createMarkers(data.data);

        $rootScope.$broadcast('map:markers:updated', markers);
    }, function (error) {
        // Display error message
    });

    allMarkersRequest.abort = function() {
        deferredAbort.resolve();
    };

    allMarkersRequest.finally(function () {
        allMarkersRequest.abort = angular.noop;
        deferredAbort = req = allMarkersRequest = null;
    });
}
```